# iphone app distribution over the air with IIS 6.0

Tags: iphone, iis, distribution, ota

I want to distribute an iphone app over the air. 
I follow the instruction to this link:
http://aaronparecki.com/How_to_Distribute_your_iOS_Apps_Over_the_Air

My web server is IIS 6.0. In the web server I
- added MIME Type (ipa & plist)
- share the Web Sharing where the .plist file was
- full control to security access of the manifest .plist file

When I clicl to the link 
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://mydomain.com/test/myApp.plist
from my iphone I have the following error
"cannot connect www.mywebsite.com"

Any idea?

Comment: can you also post the content of the myApp.plist file?
Did you ensure that the http://mydomain.com/test/myApp.plist is available and you can access that url with your iOS device?

Comment: In the folder are present the ipa file, the png file and the plist file. With the ipa and the png i am able to get with the browser while the plist I am not able (directly from my PC - Impossible find the page)

Comment: The .plist-file must be accessible and the content of the plist-file also matters (theres a link in the plist to the ipa which must be valid!)

Comment: it was wrong the mime for plist. The right value is application/x-plist